# Securing record of purchase on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, security, ipad, storekit

I have an app that allows users to purchase publications that download to their device. I would like to have an option where a user can purchase a year long subscription and be able to have unlimited downloads.

How I would like for it to work is as follows:

When user purchases the subscription - it makes an entry in a plist (or something) saying that the 2011 subscription was purchased.

Code in my store viewController well then look at this property, and if the subscription has been purchased, it will change all my purchase buttons to download buttons and bypass all the storeKit stuff.

My issue is with the security of this file. I'm not really sure what people are able to do when they jail break their device.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I can do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that they can do everything when jailbreaking there iPhone.
Save the informations about successful purchases on a server. On the device just store some key to identify the user on the server.

Comment: This is correct, assuming you have a server that can store this stuff. If not, then just don't worry about it. Jailbroken devices are sort of lost anyways.

Comment: speaking of - I had heard of some developers attempting to get their app to shut down if it was jailbroken - anyone know how Apple feels about this?

Comment: I heard, that apple entered a patent for "remote support", by resetting the software to default if a corrupted installation was detected...